# Vagrant up and VM doesn't work Fedora 22

Tags: kernel, vagrant, virtualbox, fedora

I have a problem, when I want use vagrant up I getting error

```
The provider 'virtualbox' that was requested to back the machine
'default' is reporting that it isn't usable on this system. The
reason is shown below:

VirtualBox is complaining that the kernel module is not loaded. Please
run `VBoxManage --version` or open the VirtualBox GUI to see the error
message which should contain instructions on how to fix this error.
```

After write `VBoxManage --version` I getting

```
WARNING: The vboxdrv kernel module is not loaded. Either there is no module
         available for the current kernel (4.2.3-200.fc22.x86_64) or it failed to
         load. Please recompile the kernel module and install it by

           sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup

         You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
4.2.32r101581
```

and `sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup`

I getting error

```
Stopping VirtualBox kernel modules                         [  OK  ]
Uninstalling old VirtualBox DKMS kernel modulesError! Could not locate dkms.conf file.
File:  does not exist.
                                                           [  OK  ]
Removing old VirtualBox netadp kernel module               [  OK  ]
Removing old VirtualBox netflt kernel module               [  OK  ]
Removing old VirtualBox kernel module                      [  OK  ]
Trying to register the VirtualBox kernel modules using DKMSError! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.2.3-200.fc22.x86_64 (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/vboxhost/4.2.32/build/make.log for more information.
                                                           [ERROR]
  (Failed, trying without DKMS)
Recompiling VirtualBox kernel modules                      [ERROR]
  (Look at /var/log/vbox-install.log to find out what went wrong)
```

I don't know where is a problem, I tried update kernel-devel, kernel-headers, dkms etc. I downgrade VirtualBox from 4.3.30 to 4.2.32 and nothing work, please, help me with this problem. When I had 4.3.30 version VirtualBox `sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup` don't worked, I got problem with `vboxdrv` - command does not exist.Yesterday I worked normally, I turned off machine and PC, today, when I wanted use `vagrant up` I got this problem.

Sorry for my English, please, help me with this, thanks for every answer's!

//EDIT:

I adding

> /var/lib/dkms/vboxhost/4.2.32/build/make.log
>   /var/log/vbox-install.log

Comment: Did you take a look at `/var/lib/dkms/vboxhost/4.2.32/build/make.log` and `/var/log/vbox-install.log`?

Comment: Yes and i don't understand nothing.

`Building module:
cleaning build area...
make KERNELRELEASE=4.2.3-200.fc22.x86_64 -C /lib/modules/4.2.3-200.fc22.x86_64/build M=/var/lib/dkms/vboxhost/4.2.32/build..............(bad exit status: 2)
Failed to install using DKMS, attempting to install without
@                                                                                            
"/var/log/vbox-install.log" 52L, 18326C

`

Comment: And `/var/log/vbox-install.log` ? (it's better if you edit your question to include those)

Comment: Sorry, i wanted add logs from error, but i couldn't do this, i don't know why.

Answer (score 7):

1. Please run

   sudo yum update
2. Please make sure Vagrant and Virtualbox are in their latest version.
3. In case you already installed and updated kernel-devel, and you received the error

> vboxdrv - command does not exist

please run:

```
sudo /usr/lib/virtualbox/vboxdrv.sh setup
```

Comment: `sudo /usr/lib/virtualbox/vboxdrv.sh setup` command does not exist.

Comment: The latest version of VirtualBox at the moment is 5.0.6. You seem to still use 4.*?

Answer (score 4):

The **VirtualBox** Linux kernel driver (**vboxdrv**) is probably not loaded. You may not have the kernel driver installed for the kernel that is running, if so you may do as **root**:

```
dnf install akmod-VirtualBox kernel-devel-$(uname -r)
```

If you installed **VirtualBox** packages and you don't want to reboot the system, you may need to load the kernel driver, doing as **root**:

```
akmods; systemctl restart systemd-modules-load.service
```

Also, remember to install a **supported version of VirtualBox**!!

Comment: `akmods; systemctl restart systemd-modules-load.service` did the trick for me, rebooting didn't

Answer (score 3):

I want to add that you must have gcc installed... For that make sure you get the development tools group installed before anything else. Also, you need your current kernel source code.

1. `sudo dnf install "kernel-devel-uname-r == $(uname -r)"`
2. `sudo dnf groupinstall "Development Tools"`
3. `sudo dnf update`
4. `sudo /usr/lib/virtualbox/vboxdrv.sh setup`

That should do it for most running VirtualBox 5.* Fedora 2[23].

Answer (score 0):

`sudo /usr/lib/virtualbox/vboxdrv.sh setup` this line solved the error on ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Try sudo akmods, if not work you should try install sudo apt-get install akmods. I this too wont working try reinstall vbox-akmods.

Answer (score 0):

After long and painful trials, here's the solution I found.
It is problem with Virtualbox rpm till version `5.0.20`.
The issue is fixed in Test build `5.0.21`. Get test build from https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Testbuilds

Here's reference to the issue https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/14866